# Function to erase every post from a taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, functions

I'd like to have a piece of code that erase every single post from a taxonomy of a post type when triggered.
How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily query all the posts with a `taxquery`, and loop through the results, deleting them one by one.

`wp_delete_post()` gives you the option of moving a post to the trash, or forcing to delete it - so be careful with that.

To be sure that you delete the right posts, you can create a list of the posts to be deleted instead of deleting them directly.

Voila - here come the codes:

```
function f711_delete_all_posts_from_taxonomy() {

    $args = array(
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'post', // or whatever posttype you want to delete
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'slug-to-be-deleted'
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $thispost ) {

        wp_delete_post( $thispost->ID, true ); //set second parameter to false to move the post to the trash

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try now. I just tried to make one myself, it was similar to yours but for some reason it erased every single post of the whole post_type. Thank god I had a backup...